# Retornar campos a partir de parametros

Tags: sql

Boa noite,

Preciso que o retorno de um SELECT seja dependente do parametro que for passado no SELECT

Exemplo
declare @variavel nvarchar(50)

Select 
         campoa, 
         campob, 
         campoc, 
         campod, 
         campoe,

from tabela

eu preciso que se:

@variaval = campoa 
retorne: select campoa, campob from tabela

se

@variavel = campob
retorne: select campob, campoc, campod from tabela

Como fazer essa lógica?

Comment: Isso se faz através da linguagem de programação que vai chamar o banco. Cada linguagem tem um jeito e cada banco tem um jeito. Qual é o seu banco e a linguagem que vc está utilizando ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Bom dia...obrigado pela resposta Pela regra a solução deverá ser feita via banco de dados sql server

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isto o que precisa.

```
DECLARE @Variavel AS VARCHAR(MAX); DECLARE @ComandoSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Variavel = 'campoa';

IF (@Variavel = 'campoa')
    BEGIN 
        SET @ComandoSQL = 'SELECT campoa, campob, campoc, campod, campoe FROM Tabela' 
    END 
ELSE IF (@Variavel = 'campob')
    BEGIN 
        SET @ComandoSQL = 'SELECT campob, campoc, campod FROM Tabela'
    END 

/*Mostra o comando sql gerado*/
SELECT @ComandoSQL

/*Executa o comando sql gerado*/
EXEC (@ComandoSQL)
```